# Android Studio application not installing

Tags: android, android-studio

My android application is not launching

Here is full error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'D:\Users\a.ayushi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to create install session with 'cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -S 5528668''
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

I am using physical device for my app. I have tried all other solution like reboot, invalidate cache
there is also enough space in my device,
in manifest file this is also set: android:exported="true"
but nothing is working. Also I tried to launch New project with Empty Activity that is also not installing.
The same application when I tried with adb, it gets installed. Hence I think there is some problem in Android Studio settings.

Comment: I don't think `android:exported="true"` is relevant. It's used to specify if a Broadcast receiver can receive messages from outside the app.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your problem. It seems u are able to install the application through adb, so what is the actual problem?

Comment: @Goutham I am not able to install from Android studio, to debug my application

Comment: @Peter Bruins in manifest file a launchable activity must be exported, generally it is MainActivity under which we mention this property

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it is trying to install on your physical device and not on some emulator?